# FATAL: could not locate required checkpoint record

Tags: postgresql, restore

```
cp: can't stat '/var/lib/postgresql/cluster/0000000100000022000000FE': No such file or directory
2018-12-06 20:39:33.745 UTC [264] LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2018-12-06 20:39:33.745 UTC [264] FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
```

I want restore postgres cluster with pg_basebackup, but i receive this error, when I run postgres. How to fix?

Comment: This question is much better suited for dba.stackexchange.com. This site is for programming questions, and you're definitely in admin territory with this problem.

Comment: You didn't create a `recovery.conf`, I guess. Follow the documentation.

Comment: I did create recovery.conf